# Applying SQLite Array to Scrolling Activity?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-nestedscrollview

Firstly, I'm extremely unsure on the majority of Android coding, this is only my second day doing it, so please excuse any mistakes I make in my explanations!

I've got a database via SQLite and currently display my data via a listView. Currently, it works fine displaying the data and I can scroll through and click on it no issues. However, I'd like to place my data within the "Scrolling Activity" template you can find in Android Studio. From Googling around, I understand somewhat that you can't place a listView in a nestedScrollView, which is what the activity uses.

I am unsure, however, how to display my data from the database without using a listView. Could somebody please help me either convert the listView into something compatible, or explain a way to combine them (Hacky methods are fine for now!)

I've displayed all of the necessary code below.

MainActivity.java:

```
mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    obj.setEmptyView(emptyText);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayContact.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

content_scrolling.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="uk.ac.tees.q5065885.diary.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/emptyText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />



</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Apologies for any mistakes, as I say, this is my second day; I'm learning as quick as I can!

Comment: You have an adapter and a ListView. That is all you need for scrolling. What is the issue with this code?

Comment: Note: CursorAdapter is preferred over ArrayAdapter when using the SQLite database with a ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can create views programmatically and add them to LinearLayout on the fly. You can use any kind of view, but in this example I wanted to keep things clear so I assumed that your contacts are Strings and you want to just show them as TextViews. You can try something like this:

```
mydb = new DBHelper(this);
List<String> contacts = mydb.getAllCotacts();
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
for(String data : contacts) {
    //Create a view for an LinearLayout
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    //Do whatever you like with a view - add listener, adjust style, add text etc.
    textView.setOnClickListener(...);
    textView.setText(data);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    //Add textView to linearLayout
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

xml (not very pretty, customize it if you like :))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="uk.ac.tees.q5065885.diary.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
              android:orientation="vertical"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to get this working but I can't get my head round it. I think I've replaced my code with the above code, however I'm not sure what to put in my XML now?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Sorry, I should have explained that more thoroughly. I' ve checked it and works fine. Ask me if you'll face any problems, though.

Comment: I've applied this and my array still doesn't display within the screen. I should also mention that you still need to be able to click on each piece of data displayed to get a custom interaction for the piece. IE: each Name displayed, you click on it, and it takes you to details of that person. Would this still work with your version? Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: "my array still doesn't display within the screen." <- I don't get it sorry. Like nothing is displayed in the scroll view? According to your quesiton, as I've written you can add custom onClick action while creating the view in the loop
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   //your code goes here
                }
            });
So if I understood correctly, you return objects which contain names, and you want to display them right? And passing name to setText doesn't work?

Comment: @Bari - The question was about SQLite + ListView, not dynamic views... The ArrayAdapter in the question should work

Comment: @cricket_007 - Well, actually the question says "I am unsure, however, how to display my data from the database without using a listView. Could somebody please help me either convert the listView into something compatible or explain a way to combine them (Hacky methods are fine for now!)". I would do it that way, not saying it's the best possible solution :)

Comment: Well, the question asked about the "Scrolling Activity" template, which I would assume uses a RecyclerView

Comment: After a lot of messing I've got it displaying, which is perfect, however I'm still unsure how to be able to click on each entry to go to the details, like it did before?